# How much quote is too much quote?

Tags: discussion, quotes

Lately I've been finding questions like [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125576/why-did-clara-want-to-be-like-the-doctor) that it's only a big chunk of text pasted from probably chakoteya.net, a fan-made site for show transcripts like Doctor Who.

I know I've seen more, but can't find them anymore. They were probably edited already, as should this one, but I was wondering...is there a policy, or a rule, of how much of a script can be just pasted in the site? I know those are fan-made, and not official, but I was wondering if they could cause trouble for copyright infrigement or something...

Comment: I think that's just one guy posting a lot, and if you can talk him into trimming his quotes, everyone would appreciate it. I guess copyright is a consideration though...

Comment: @amarillo Yeah, this is an Andrew Casali problem really. Still, the general question is a useful one to discuss here.

Comment: See also: ["Quotes on the site cover how much of the Harry Potter books?"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3577/4918)

Comment: We also have users who quote volumes of text for answers - far more than is necessary to illustrate or back up their point. Simply quote the relevant lines and maybe a few more for context, and link to the full source for users to read more if they wish.

Comment: How much quote would a quotechuck chuck, if a quotechuck could chuck quote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two questions here; Copyright and readability. I'll address them in that order.

### Copyright

Since these are fan-transcriptions, copyright *is* an issue, but not much of one. This is a site dedicated to discussion of sci-fi and as such, posting even very large chunks of text (short of entire book chapters and large sections of original scripts) is well within the scope of "fair use" under pretty much every definition. Note that as far as I am aware, there have been **zero takedown requests for any quoted text anywhere on the network, ever.** You're safe to post and if you go overboard, it's likely that a high-rep user or one of the moderation team will tell you well before it becomes a legal issue.

### Readability

Ah, now here's the rub. Posting slabs of formatted text makes questions next to impossible to read, let alone answer. You should pick quotes sparingly to illustrate your main thesis rather than allowing the quote to stand as the actual question. The link you've provided is a perfect example of a question that could be good, but has been ruined by someone overdoing it with the quotes.

My suggestion would be that you should ruthlessly edit everything you write, then look at all the quotes to see if they're *really necessary*. If you have even the slightest doubt, cut it out and see if helps. There's no hard 'n' fast rule, but if a quote forms more than 50% of a question or more than 75% of an answer, then you've probably gone too far.

Comment: "*Posting slabs of formatted text makes questions next to impossible to read, let alone answer. You should pick quotes sparingly to illustrate your main thesis rather than allowing the quote to stand as the actual question.*" - I'll be quoting this to the OP of that question in future.

Comment: Yeah — as long as the question can be understood by someone who’s familiar with the work in question (because if they’re not, then they’re not in a position to answer), then quotes don’t need to be added — a synopsis will likely be shorter and easier to read than quotes, and can directly communicate what the asker doesn’t understand.