# Late acceptances of story-identification answers

Tags: discussion, story-identification, accepted-answer

[This story-identification question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36946/unexplainable-darkness-for-three-days-brazilian-author) was asked on June 16, 2013; I answered it on July 1, 2013; and my answer was accepted today, April 23, 2021, almost 8 years later. Is this a record?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As it turns out, these records have been broken.

Our current overall record is over 10 years:

[Were there two elves named Glorfindel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9828/19561)

And our current record for [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) is over 9 years:

[Story/movie about Earth broken into pieces and then reformed by the survivors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22206/19561)

View [the current Top 15](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1400219) for yourself over on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

---

[Looks like it](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1400219). The previous record was about 7 years.

[Short story about two brothers leading an expedition to the prehistoric past, one (Orren? Owen?) is killed and erased from history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5192/19561)

Our overall record of over 8 years hasn't been broken, though.

[What evidence supposedly supports Tau as related to the Necrontyr?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22850/19561)

Here's the top 15 at the time of answering (yours isn't in SEDE yet).

| Question | Tags | AnswerDate | AcceptDate | DaysBetween |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [What evidence supposedly supports Tau as related to the Necrontyr?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22850/19561) | [warhammer-40k](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k) | 2012-08-31 | 2021-01-08 | 3052 |
| [Gaiman's Hamnet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/20827/19561) | [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics)[neil-gaiman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neil-gaiman) | 2012-07-20 | 2020-09-25 | 2989 |
| [Why Was the Burrow Burned Down in Half-Blood Prince?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17540/19561) | [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) | 2012-05-31 | 2020-05-06 | 2897 |
| [How does Bruce travel from The Pit to Gotham City?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/20920/19561) | [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc)[batman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman)[nolan-batman-trilogy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nolan-batman-trilogy)[the-dark-knight-rises](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dark-knight-rises) | 2012-08-18 | 2020-06-11 | 2854 |
| [How do the mutant levels correlate with the mutant classifications?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7188/19561) | [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel)[x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men) | 2011-11-23 | 2019-09-10 | 2848 |
| [What happened to Pixie in the mines of Abergylid?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17143/19561) | [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel)[x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men) | 2012-06-16 | 2020-03-24 | 2838 |
| [Why did Lily's enchantments work for Voldemort?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/32157/19561) | [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter)[voldemort](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voldemort)[magical-theory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-theory) | 2013-02-24 | 2020-05-06 | 2628 |
| [Short story about two brothers leading an expedition to the prehistoric past, one (Orren? Owen?) is killed and erased from history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5192/19561) | [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification)[time-travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel)[short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories)[prehistoric](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prehistoric) | 2011-09-10 | 2018-10-08 | 2585 |
| [Where does the girl from episode 15 end up in the next episode?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/39959/19561) | [sliders](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliders) | 2013-09-19 | 2020-09-30 | 2568 |
| [How did the Witch King of Angmar get his sword back?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/34783/19561) | [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium)[the-lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lord-of-the-rings)[adaptation-comparison](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptation-comparison)[nazgul](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nazgul) | 2013-04-28 | 2020-05-06 | 2565 |
| [Who Inherited Bag End?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/37949/19561) | [the-lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lord-of-the-rings)[tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium)[the-hobbit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit) | 2013-07-09 | 2020-05-06 | 2493 |
| [How did Snape get the fake Sword of Gryffindor into Gringotts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/38185/19561) | [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) | 2013-07-15 | 2020-05-06 | 2487 |
| [Do all Federation starships have stasis chambers for the entire crew?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8001/19561) | [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek)[star-trek-voyager](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-voyager) | 2011-12-19 | 2018-07-31 | 2416 |
| [When was Hogwarts founded?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18550/19561) | [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter)[hogwarts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hogwarts) | 2012-06-17 | 2019-01-18 | 2406 |
| [Why does Bifur have an axe in his head?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22945/19561) | [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium)[the-hobbit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit) | 2012-09-03 | 2019-04-02 | 2402 |

Comment: Thanks! Two good answers but yours came in first so this is the one I accept. I thought about holding off accepting until 2030 so you could have the new overall record, but I might not live that long and anyway meta doesn't count.

Comment: @user14111 FWIW [This answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3588/58193) wins on meta with a gap of a little under 5 years.

Comment: Now you need to look at the difference between _asking date_ and acceptance date.

Answer (score 10):

I created [the following SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1400223/longest-gap-from-answering-to-accepting) to test this:

```
SELECT a.Id AS [Post Link],
       a.CreationDate AS [Answer Time],
       v.CreationDate AS [Accept Time],
       CONVERT(varchar, DATEDIFF(s, a.CreationDate, v.CreationDate) / 86400)
     + ':'
     + CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, (DATEDIFF(s, a.CreationDate, v.CreationDate) % 86400) * 1000, 0), 114)
     AS [Difference]
FROM Posts a
JOIN Votes v ON a.Id = v.PostId
WHERE VoteTypeId = 1
AND DATEDIFF(s, a.CreationDate, v.CreationDate) > 31557600
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(s, a.CreationDate, v.CreationDate) DESC
```

The top 5 results are as follows:

| Answer | Answer Time | Accept Time | Answerer | Questioner | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [What evidence supposedly supports Tau as related to the Necrontyr?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22852) | 2012-08-31 23:22:28 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | [Thaddeus Howze](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2765) | [AncientSwordRage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804) | 3051:00:37:32 |
| [Gaiman's Hamnet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/20843) | 2012-07-20 21:56:52 | 2020-09-25 00:00:00 | [dlanod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4056) | [Andrés E. Caicedo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7823) | 2988:02:03:08 |
| [Why Was the Burrow Burned Down in Half-Blood Prince?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17541) | 2012-05-31 07:48:43 | 2020-05-06 00:00:00 | [Tango](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693) | [Slytherincess](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500) | 2896:16:11:17 |
| [How does Bruce travel from The Pit to Gotham City?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22242) | 2012-08-18 18:21:59 | 2020-06-11 00:00:00 | [Jack B Nimble](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1148) | [Wipqozn](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2091) | 2853:05:38:01 |
| [How do the mutant levels correlate with the mutant classifications?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7192) | 2011-11-23 02:58:50 | 2019-09-10 00:00:00 | [Thaddeus Howze](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2765) | [Jack B Nimble](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1148) | 2847:21:01:10 |

Your difference actually comes in at roughly 2997 days 20:12:45 and so when SEDE updates it will come in second overall but the top one for [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification)!

---

<sub>*A markdown friendly version of the query can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1400229/longest-gap-from-answering-to-accepting-markdown-version) if anyone ever wants to add to this.*</sub>

Comment: I blame those damn pesky mods from taking away your victory!

Comment: It's certainly the record for Story-ID